# Alt+Shift+Tab not working on Ubuntu Budgie

Tags: shortcut-keys, application-switcher, ubuntu-budgie

The shortcut Alt+Tab is used to switch between applications. I use this keyboard shortcut a lot, and it works great on Ubuntu Budgie, but I can't reverse switch between applications when using Alt+Shift+Tab (reverse switching is going in the other direction when switching between applications), it looks like the Shift key is completely ignored.

Comment: What is the "maj" button?

Comment: it is the button that is used to write capital letters, just above the `ctrl` button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> is not implemented in budgie-desktop version 10.2.9 nor 10.3.1.

Currently it is an upstream [feature request](https://github.com/budgie-desktop/budgie-desktop/issues/917) looking for a developer to implement this.